# Get a list of colors used in word and pdf documents using php?

Tags: php, phpdocx

Is there is any php-based library that can extract all the formatting information from a word and a pdf document?

Basically, I need a list of all the different font colors used in the document.

I am working on a utility, where user uploads a document ( word or pdf) and it counts the number of color and black and white pages !

I checked livedocx, phpdocx but couldn't find any relevant. If someone has worked, can someone please help me out with this.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to save a page to an image and then analyze the colors of image

Comment: Documents are like close to 200 pages. Wouldn't it be time consuming? Any other alternative ?

But yaa this can be the last resort. Thanks.